# AudioKit and AUv3 Audio Effect

Tags: ios, audiokit, auv3

Is it possible to chain of the AUAudioUnits from the AudioKit/SoundpipeAudioKit for creating of a AUv3 audio effect extension?

I found a great tutorials for creating of the AUv3 instruments with AudioKit which uses an audio chain like: Instrument -> Effect. It uses the AVAudioEngine for chaining of instrument/effect and the manualRenderingBlock for rendering of the audio, which is quite straightforward if the instrument/generator is used, but I am not clear whether it is possible to use similar effects chain (builded from SoundpipeAudioKit component) for processing an audio as AUv3 Audio Effect (where the input audio buffer coming from?).
So, please, is there any way how to use the AudioKit/SoundpipeAudioKit for building of the AUv3 Audio Effect app/extension? btw. I found a nice tutorial which uses a AUAudioUnit component from the SoundpipeAudioKit for building of the AUv3 effect extension, but I am not sure how to chain multiple AUAudioUnit together.